# How to extract the selected value from a datalist with Thymeleaf and Spring

Tags: java, spring, web, thymeleaf

This is my html file. I did a list with all my files from DB.

```
 <div class="container">
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/getFiles}" method="post">

        File Name: 
        <input list="files" name="files" />
        <datalist id="files">
            <option th:each="file: ${files}" th:value=" ${file.fileName}"></option>
        </datalist>
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

When I select a file I want to know what file I select. 
This is the controller. The File from post method is always empty...

```
@Autowired
public FileRepository fileRepository;

@GetMapping("/getFiles")
public String fileGet(Model model) {

    List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();

    files = fileRepository.findAll();

    model.addAttribute("files", files);

    model.addAttribute("file", new File());

    return "filesFromDB";
}

@PostMapping("/getFiles")
public String filePost(@ModelAttribute("file") File file, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("fileName", file.getFileName());

    System.out.println("File: " + file.getFileName());

    return "resultFileDB";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your must add select tag in your datalist.

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/getFiles}" method="post">

    File Name: 
    <input list="files" name="files" />
    <datalist id="files">
     <select>
        <option th:each="file: ${files}" th:value=" ${file.fileName}">
        </option>
     </select>
    </datalist>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```